# Mapping array returns undefined values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I am mapping an array called tours

```
   export const tourData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    city: "new york",
    img: "./img/newyork.jpeg",
    name: "new york bridge tour",
    info:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel,repellendus!"
  },
```

as shown below

```
 state={
    tours: tourData
} 
 render(){
    const {tours} = this.state;

    return(
        <section className="tourlist">
          {tours.map(tour => {
              return (
                  <Tour key={tour.id} tour={tour} removeTour={this.removeTour}/>
              )
          })}
        </section>
    )
}
```

and i pass the tour as a prop into the Tour component.

```
const {id , city , img, name, info} = this.props.tour;
    const {removeTour} = this.props;
```

The webapp works well but when i make a test for the Tour component and i pass in values as props

```
 const props ={
            id : 1,
            city: 'Test City ',
            img: 'Test img',
            name: 'Test name',
            info: 'Test Info'
        }
```

i get errors like

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

but the webapp works fine.
need some help on this and thanks in advance

Comment: how you `tours` variable's value looks  like ?

Comment: Did your `tours` variable get called before you initialize it?

Comment: @P4uB0rd4 i called it

Comment: *array called tours* That looks like a object

Comment: @TheMaster it actually an array

Comment: How do you pass the `props` value and how do you get the values in your `Tour` component? As `props.props.id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while passing values to the props of Tour component in your tests you should be doing something like this

```
const props = {
  tour: {
    id : 1,
    city: 'Test City',
    img: 'Test img',
    name: 'Test name',
    info: 'Test Info'
  }
};
```

since inside your Tour component it is reading from `this.props.tour`.

Comment: Glad to help..!!